# Error message : Unknown column 'a.id_configuration' in 'order clause'

Tags: prestashop

With this code i would like print a tab with some fields in prestashop back office. But i got an error message: : Unknown column 'a.id_configuration' in 'order clause'

````
    <?php

      public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'order_invoice'; // SQL table name, will be prefixed with _DB_PREFIX_
        $this->className = 'OrderInvoice'; // PHP class name
        $this->allow_export = true; // allow export in CSV, XLS..
        $this->fields_list = [
          'id_order_invoice' => ['title' => $this->trans('ID', [], 'Admin.Global'),'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'],
          'number' => ['title' => $this->trans('Number', [], 'Admin.Global'),'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'],
          'date_add' => ['title' => $this->trans('Date', [], 'Admin.Global'), 'type'=>'datetime'],
          'total_products_wt' => ['title' => $this->trans('Total products', [], 'Admin.Global'),
            'align' => 'text-right',
            'type' => 'price',
          ],
          'total_shipping_tax_incl' => ['title' => $this->trans('Total shipping', [], 'Admin.Global'),
            'align' => 'text-right',
            'type' => 'price',
          ],
          'total_paid_tax_incl' => ['title' => $this->trans('Total paid', [], 'Admin.Global'),
            'align' => 'text-right',
            'type' => 'price',
          ],
        ];

      }

          ?>
```
````

Comment: did you get the source code from https://blog.floriancourgey.com/2018/04/edit-your-invoices-in-prestashop? Please credit author

Comment: Yes, i apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Since it states it's an error within the order clause (`ORDER BY`), we'd edit the `orderBy` variable like this:

```php
$this->_orderBy = 'id_order_invoice';
```

You can also edit the identifier since it seems to be using the wrong identifier to begin with:

```php
$this->identifier = 'id_order_invoice';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used your answer to solve my problem. So I do not have the error message anymore.